# Argument invalid with every build in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, provisioning, arguments

No matter what I try, I get an Argument is Invalid error in Xcode when I try to build to my iPhone.  It works fine in the simulator.  The problem is not specific to one project, it happens with any project, even when I create a new one.  When I run the console it displays this

[image]

I tried deleting and re-adding the provisioning profiles, and I've gone through every setting to look for spaces because I heard these can cause this error.  Can anyone help?  I don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a symbolic link (ln -s) in your project directory, it will work on the simulator, but cause a “The argument is invalid” error if the target is a real iOS device. (**Xcode 4.5.2**)

Comment: `find ./ -type l -exec ls -l {} \;` for viewing all symlinks into project directory

Answer (score 0):

You may check if you have a space somewhere in the settings, such as the product name or so. These cause these kind of errors in many cases....

Also sometimes a symlink in your bundle can be the reason - depending on how you set up your file structures in the app bundle...

Comment: it's happening with every project though, what setting would be carried over to new projects?

Comment: probably a standard installation or target folder. can you post your install log - or check it for spaces in names, symlinks, or any non-standard characters. I would assume there is a problem somewhere with defined folders and/or installed library locations...

Answer (score 0):

Actually this looks like and xcode error because it cant find those .m files. So here is a post that responded to hopefully it helps. It looks like you are gonna have to do some installation and reinstallation. [XCode Update - iOS Link Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575437/xcode-update-ios-link-error/7576163#7576163)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are working with Git. This often happens due to issues in your local build. Take the latest pull from the develop branch and check if this solves your issue. If this doesn't work, you might want to manually check the build settings for your app.