# Application crashing in Distribution mode not in debug mode

Tags: iphone, debugging, build, distribution

I am facing an issue for which I am giving a try a to explain here. (I don't know I will be able to explain).

I made an iPhone application having the **base sdk version current** and **target OS devices as 3.0** the application was running well until I tried to build for iPhone 5.0.

Now when I am making the build for iPhone 5.0 the build is running fine in debug mode but its crashing in Distribution mode. I am consuming some webservice in the application using SOAP. The first step of authentication using the webservices is working fine in both mode but I am not able to move further in distribution mode. Moreover I feel very helpless as I am not able to find the right place from where the issue is being generated.

I know that's a weird thing to ask but still I am hopeful that somebody would have faced a similar challenge and would have overcome it. So the knowledge-full would enlighten me too.

Comment: Do you have any variable in methods that you do not set to `nil`. In debug mode all variables are set to `nil` but in release mode this is not the case.

Comment: Does is work fine in 'Debug' mode?

Answer (score 0):

What is "Distribution mode"? Do you mean "Release" configuration? Which one you have? llvm 3.0? Is your project ARC-enabled?...

(Anyhow, first thing I would do is replacing -Os Fastest, Smallest optimization with no optimization. Try to run.)

Comment: I had some troubles with llvm 3.0 + -Os + loops on iPod. But in my case I could illustrate it with simple example.

Answer (score 0):

Try these 
[iPhone Codesign object file format invalid or unsuitable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842717/iphone-codesign-object-file-format-invalid-or-unsuitable)
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/5429-codesign-verification-nightmare.html