# object file format invalid or unsuitable running application in ipad device

Tags: iphone, provisioning-profile

I have created a projest where i have all the certificates created but when i try to run the code it gives me error..

My code used to work on same certificates and code. i installed Xcode 4 and xcode 3.2 on same system. I uninstall all and installed xcode 3.2 and now it is giving me following error.

> CodeSign "build/Release-iphoneos/SAT Study Guide.app"
>   cd "/Volumes/MANOJ/GRE Study Guide"
>   setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>   setenv _CODESIGN_ALLOCATE_ /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
>   /usr/bin/codesign -f -s "iPhone Developer: abhishek sonawane (7576SD6Q4Q)" "--resource-rules=/Volumes/MANOJ/GRE Study Guide/build/Release-iphoneos/SAT Study Guide.app/ResourceRules.plist" --entitlements "/Volumes/MANOJ/GRE Study Guide/build/SAT Study Guide.build/Release-iphoneos/SAT Study Guide.build/SAT Study Guide.xcent" "/Volumes/MANOJ/GRE Study Guide/build/Release-iphoneos/SAT Study Guide.app"
>   /Volumes/MANOJ/GRE Study Guide/build/Release-iphoneos/SAT Study Guide.app: object file format invalid or unsuitable
>   Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

any help will be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Could you add some more information? It might be hard to tell what the problem is with only this..

Comment: is it because of any file i added in my project? it also gives error with my distribution certificates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This same question was asked multiple times on this site... Here's one with a few different answers. It looks like different things work for different people.

[iPhone Codesign object file format invalid or unsuitable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842717/iphone-codesign-object-file-format-invalid-or-unsuitable)