# change xcrun developer path

Tags: xcode

How can I change the directory at which xcrun is pointing ? currently is pointing to

> xcrun: Error: could not stat active Xcode path
>   '/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode44-DP7.app/Contents/Developer'. (No such file or
>   directory)

I need to change the location.
Thank you.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Comment: This is interesting: This changes xcode version system wise, is it possible to select during specific build in progress...? I have use case where parallel builds are running ... System wide changes will not helpful for me..

Answer (score 45):

Use `xcode-select -switch` to choose which version of Xcode you're using by default.

Comment: On OSX Yosemite use `xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app`.

Comment: please try this 

1.xcode-select --install
2.sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

Answer (score 30):

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Comment: This was it for me. When I uninstalled xcode from my mac git wasn't working anymore. I just executed this line and everything was fine without installing xcode again.

Answer (score 14):

In my case, i had to:

1. Install Xcode's command line tools, going to *preferences* -> *Locations* and setting a correct value to *Command Line Tools*.
2. In *Downloads* -> *Components tab*, I clicked install on a line called *Command Line tools*.
3. Marmalade started working fine with Xcode.

Comment: This was the answer for me, and you if you don't have the command line tools set.

Answer (score 11):

If you run this command:

```
$ xcode-select -p
```

it will print to screen as below:

*/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode44-DP7.app/Contents/Developer* ( in your case)

To change it to default, you can do as follow:

```
$ sudo xcode-select -r
Password:
```

Check again:

```
$ xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Get more information from:

```
$ xcode-select

Usage: xcode-select [options]

Print or change the path to the active developer directory. This directory
controls which tools are used for the Xcode command line tools (for example,
xcodebuild) as well as the BSD development commands (such as cc and make).

Options:
  -h, --help                  print this help message and exit
  -p, --print-path            print the path of the active developer directory
  -s <path>, --switch <path>  set the path for the active developer directory
  -v, --version               print the xcode-select version
  -r, --reset                 reset to the default command line tools path
```

Answer (score 10):

**Open xcode and navigate to preferences...**

[image]

**Select Location of xcode from command line tools.**

[image]
**After that perform command from terminal.**

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, override the DEVELOPER_DIR environment variable instead:

```
export DEVELOPER_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"
```

This setting is unique to each user account.  If present, it overrides the `xcode-select` choice.

Optional: you can make this persist between login sessions by editing your .bash_profile file.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to have xcode installed in order to use xcrun.

Just install the xcode command line tools and switch to it.

Install x code command line tools

```
xcode-select --install
```

Switch to command line tools

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Answer (score 2):

After uninstall xcode?

Run this in console

```
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to get Git Clone through Terminal.

1. User-Mac-mini:~ user_name$ cd /Users/yser_name/Documents/Developer/Xcode_Projects/Xcode_Proj/AAG/EJ
2. user-Mac-mini:EJ user_name$ git clone https://smaplebitbucket.org/projectname/sample.git

I got below error:

```
xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Applications/Xcode 8.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist, use `xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools (or see `man xcode-select`)
```

Intially I had two xcode 7.3 and 8.0. I kept name of **xcode**  for 7.0 and **xcode 8** for 8.0.

I deleted the **xcode** for 7.0 from Applications and rename **xcode 8** to **xcode**.
In Xcode preference it was poiting to location **xcode 8** but it was not there.

I changed the location using command :

```
  sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Git Command worked and i was able to download the project from GIT.

you can also do it from Xcode preference too.

[image]

It worked.

Answer (score 0):

sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools works for me.

For your information I screw up my config with this :

```
 sw_vers -productVersion | grep -E '^10\.([89]|10)' >/dev/null && bash -c "[ -d /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain ] && sudo -u $(ls -ld /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain | awk '{print $3}') bash -c 'ln -vs XcodeDefault.xctoolchain /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX$(sw_vers -productVersion).xctoolchain' || sudo bash -c 'mkdir -vp /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX$(sw_vers -productVersion).xctoolchain/usr && for i in bin include lib libexec share; do ln -s /usr/${i} /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX$(sw_vers -productVersion).xctoolchain/usr/${i}; done'"
```