# How to use OpenCV in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv, image-processing, open-source

I want to use OpenCV framework in my project. But while building opencv from source , i am getting errors. I am using [this link](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/ios_install/ios_install.html#ios-installation) to install opencv

I am getting this error in  terminal of which i am attaching images.
[image]

[image]

i also used opencv2.framework which is already built and add this in my project but its showing linker error.
Please help me to use openCV.
Thanks in advance. . . .

Comment: Please, please, pretty please, don't ever use images of textual data. Every time you do so, a cute kitten gets her tail stomped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to fix it...

- Google your error: ["xcrun error: could not stat active Xcode path"](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22xcrun%20error%3A%20could%20not%20stat%20active%20Xcode%20path%22)
- Click on the first link and go to
  [xcrun: Error: could not stat active Xcode path '/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode45-DP1.app/Contents/Developer'. (No such file or directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961032/xcrun-error-could-not-stat-active-xcode-path-volumes-xcode-xcode45-dp1-app-c)
- if still unclear try the next couple of links
  [change xcrun developer path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456918/change-xcrun-developer-path)
  [Resolved: Error “Could not stat active Xcode path”](http://geek.chrislott.org/2012/resolved-error-could-not-stat-active-xcode-path/)

When Google and SO fail you, come back here explaining what you have tried (and post your text errors as text not image!)

As regards your linker error (what linker error? post it!) my answer here might help
[How to resolve iOS Link errors with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185716/how-to-resolve-ios-link-errors-with-opencv/14186883#14186883)