# vscode iostream file not found on macos gnu g++

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

I installed GNU GCC on macos Ventura using homebrew, it installed g++12. It is installed at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/12.2.0

I tried to write basic c++ program and tried to run/debug it in vscode using their c/c++ plugin. Here is my program

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!";
    return 0;
}
```

My vscode tasks.json is like this

```
{
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
        "command": "/opt/homebrew/bin/g++-12",
        "args": [
            "-std=c++17",
            "-stdlib=libc++",
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    }
],
"version": "2.0.0"
}
```

If I change the configuration to use /usr/bin/g++ ("command": "/usr/bin/g++") instead of gnu gcc, everything works good.

> But if I am using above configuration, vscode shows "iostream: No such file or directory" error

In both the cases if I am compiling form commandline it works.

What need to be chagned in vscode configuration?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but you can remove `using namespace std;` from that code.

Comment: Try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456918/change-xcrun-developer-path