# Multiple iOS Distribution Certificates issue

Tags: ios, certificate, distribution

We have a Distribution certificate that is set to expire in Nov. In order to get a jump on signing our current apps a colleague went ahead and created a second certificate.

Unfortunately, since downloading this cert I have been unable to sign applications with the old or the new certificate when using Terminal. Every time I attempt to sign an app in terminal and both certs are present in the keychain I get the error:

`iPhone Distribution: XXXX: ambiguous (matches "iPhone Distribution: XXXX and iPhone Distribution: XXXX in /Users/applicatonsigning/Library/Keychains/login.keychain)`

Additionally, If I delete a cert/private key and just attempt to use the old or new cert separately I get the following error:

```
XYZ.app: object file format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable.
```

Thus, far I have revoked and reassigned my Apple Developer Cert as well as tried creating a profile on my MAC to only sign with. Additionally, according to my key-chain both certs are valid and have associated private keys.

Unfortunately, I am at a complete and total loss on what to do next. I have need to start resigning apps soon but, I can't.

Any thoughts on how I can sign my application?

Comment: For the first problem there's an official documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TROUBLESHOOTING_FAQ-HOW_DO_I_RESOLVE_THE_CODESIGN_ERROR__IPHONE_DEVELOPER__OR_IPHONE_DISTRIBUTION__AMBIGUOUS_MATCHES_ For the second problem there're similar questions at SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6769927/792677 Have you already checked both ?

Answer (score 2):

Since you've tried out every possible thing, I'd suggest you to try a clean install.

(1)Go to your provisioning portal and revoke all your Distribution Certificates.(Don't worry. It won't affect anything which is already up on App Store).

(2)In your Xcode Organizer window, refresh and remove all distribution certificate from your Organizer window ONLY.(And not from provisioning portal.)

(3)In your "Keychain Access", remove/delete all distribution certificates.

(4)Create a new distribution certificate as per the instruction given on provisioning portal and submit it.

(5)Modify all your distribution profiles on the provisioning portal and make sure they are using the new distribution certificate.

(6)Download the new Distribution Certificate and and install it, such that its present on Keychain Access.(At no point of time, you should have more than one distribution certificate on your Keychain Access)

(7)Refresh the Xcode Organizer by signing in the Developer portal through Xcode.

(8)Install the new distribution certificate in Xcode if its not there already.

(9)Use the new distribution profile and clean build your app.
This should work.