# object file format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable xcode

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios6, xcode4.5, codesign

I know other similar questions have been posted, but none of those solutions worked for me.  Updated to Xcode 4.5.1 from 4.3.3 today. Got this error:

```
Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MobileApp.app/MobileApp malformed object (unknown load command 19)
/Users/garyt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MobileApp-cgojnkplmjncbaaigyvelwclibwr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MobileApp.app/: object file format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

So followed instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842717/iphone-codesign-object-file-format-invalid-or-unsuitable). Downloaded latest command line tools, tried the sudo codesign_allocate fix suggested, and checked to make sure my name and values were matching on both target and product, but still having the "object file format invalid or unsuitable error pop up".  New to cocoa/iOS dev and this wasn't a headache I was expecting.  Any help would be appreciated.  I guess I should also note everything worked fine when I was running Xcode 4.3.3, which is what I updated from.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to just delete the XCode and install a new one from Appstore.

https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12