# How to codesign an existing Mac OS X .app file for gatekeeper?

Tags: xcode, macos, codesign

I paid the $99 to get a developer license w/ Apple.  Installed Xcode 4.3.  Went to the Organizer and "Provisioning Profiles" and refreshed to download my code signing certificate.  Checked my Keychain Access and confirmed that I have "3rd Party Mac Developer *", "Developer ID*" and "Mac Developer *" certificates.

At this point the documentation from apple mentioned pulling up your project files.  I'm using Wineskin to package my Windows application, so I don't have an Xcode project.  I have a .app file produced my Wineskin.  I'd like to codesign the .app file that Wineskin produced for me.

I tried:
codesign -s "certificate name" /path/to/my.app

I tried all the possible certificate names that had my name and the word "Application" in them from my Keychain Access.

Every time I get the error "/path/to/my.app: object file format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable"

Any idea on how to get past this error?  Am I even attempting the proper command?  Or is there a different way I should go?

Comment: This question is about iOS, but may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842717/iphone-codesign-object-file-format-invalid-or-unsuitable

Comment: From that post I saw that someone mentioned to try:  export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate"

Comment: I tried that, and it got me past the error.  I used the certificate named "Mac Developer: <my name> (xxxx)".  Now I need to upload it to the internet and download it to test if Gatekeeper complains.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: I think you'll find that it won't work yet.  You have to pass a bunch more cryptic parameters to `codesign`.  What people usually do is make a toy app in Xcode 4 , find the codesign command in its log, and copy out the magic goodness (modifying the bundle ID as needed).

Comment: Yep, there must be more to it.  When I download to another Mac, I run:  codesign -vvv /path/to/my.app  and I get back:  "valid on disk" and "satisfies its Designated Requirement".  Looks good, I think.  But then when I try to run it, I get the Gatekeeper message:  “MyApp” can’t be opened because it is from an unidentified developer.

Comment: Use the certificate that starts with "Developer ID Application: "

Comment: Gordon, that was it!  I used that certificate, uploaded my application to my website, downloaded it to another computer and received no Gatekeeper warning.  Thanks!

Comment: I just realized that I didn't originally try all the certificates I said I tried.  Woops!  Thanks again, Gordon (and JWWalker), for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To summarize the comments to my questions, here are the commands I run to sign my .app file for Gatekeeper:

```
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate"
codesign --force --sign "Developer ID Application: <my name>" /path/to/my.app
```

Thanks, Gordon Davisson and JWWalker!

(edit) If this fails, I realize that installing the "Command Line Tools" from within XCode was needed.

**EDIT:**
To verify

```
$ codesign -dv --verbose=4 my.app
```

In Apple ID account make sure you have few types of certificate?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why you thanked me, because you didn't do what I said, and I don't believe anything this simple is going to work.

Comment: JWWalker, your link gave me the information I needed about the needed command "export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE...".  So thanks!  Gordon helped me with selecting the right certificate "Developer ID App...".  The script I mention above is the same script I used to sign my app (after putting in my actual cert name and my actual app name, of course).  Now I no longer get the gatekeeper warning.

Comment: That's weird, because every discussion of the issue on the Xcode mailing list says you need the `--requirements` parameter to make GateKeeper happy.

Comment: Check out this blog post.  It's where I go tthe "--force --sign" from:  http://www.hardcoded.net/devlogs/20120407

Comment: Maybe the problem I was thinking of was making the signature compatible with OS 10.6 and earlier.  See this blog post: http://www.red-sweater.com/blog/2390/developer-id-gotcha

Comment: Is joining Developer Program Mandatory ? I already have a code signing certificate from Comodo,can i use the same for my OSX app?

Comment: for me I had Developer ID Installer in the --sign directive, you have to make sure it's `Developer ID Application:`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have a valid developer certificate and a private key in your keychain.
If you have some problems with it, the certificate should be revoked via developer.apple.com and generated from the scratch (XCode > Accounts > Manage Certificates).

Then you can use `codesign`:

```sh
codesign --force --deep --sign "Apple Development: FirstName LastName (XXXXXXXXXX)" /Applications/ApplicationName.app
```

Answer (score 0):

Before using codesign command

1. Install Command line tool for Xcode from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action section. 
   (You should have a developer account to download Additional Tools.)
2. Please check for any hidden file in Payload folder like (.DStore) and if there is one please remove it

   - Navigate to Payload folder via terminal using *cd* command
   - Type ls- a command on terminal
   - if there is any hidden file apart, delete it by rm -f .DStore

This solution worked for me so please give a try....