# JDeveloper 12c getting error after migration my Apps from JDeveloper 11.1.2.4

Tags: java, ios, oracle, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have migrated my application from JDeveloper 11.1.2.4 to JDeveloper 12c(12.1.3.0). My application cleaned and compiled successfully. Application Module tested successfully. But when i am running my application (ViewController)weblogic started but application not deployed, i am getting below error in JDeveloper Console when running in iOS devices.

```
[11:04:36 AM] The following build commands failed:
[11:04:36 AM] warning: (armv7) /tmp/lto.o unable to open object file
[11:04:36 AM] warning: (armv7) /tmp/lto.o unable to open object file
[11:04:36 AM] Command-line execution failed (Return code: 65)
[11:04:36 AM] Deployment cancelled.
[11:04:36 AM] ----  Deployment incomplete  ----.
[11:04:36 AM] Failed to build the iOS application bundle.
[11:04:36 AM] Deployment failed due to one or more errors returned by '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild'.
```

The following is a summary of the returned error(s):

```
Command-line execution failed (Return code: 65)
The following build commands failed:
PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script /Users/kahunasystems/jdeveloper/mywork/NewCityLV/deploy/iOS1/build/build-output/Oracle_ADFmc_Container_Template.build/Debug-iphoneos/Oracle_ADFmc_Container_Template.build/Script-4BED853A1911CA5400134289.sh
(1 failure)
```

Any idea regarding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, After spending my two days, I got the solution

By running this line on a terminal

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate /usr/bin/
```

Thanks to [bhuvan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842717/iphone-codesign-object-file-format-invalid-or-unsuitable%5d).