# CodeSign Pods trouble

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, code-signing, reactive-cocoa

I have a project with 3 targets:

1- DemoApp - iOS App

2- DemoExt - iOS Extension

3- DemoFramework - iOS 8 Framework

I'm not sure if my podfile is setup correctly cause I'm having trouble with archiving only.
Building each of the targets works fine.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'

xcodeproj 'MyProject'

target :DemoApp do
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'
    pod 'ReactiveCocoa'
end

target : DemoExt, :exclusive => true do
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'ReactiveCocoa'
end

target : DemoFramework do
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'ReactiveCocoa'
end
```

The intent is to have Facebook installed only on DemoApp.

The DemoFramework is used on DempApp and DemoExt targets

When compiling & running everything looks fine.
Only when I try to Archive I'm getting CodeSign issues on all the ReactiveCocoa frameworks...

> CodeSign /IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/ReactiveCocoa.framework
>       cd /Pods
>       export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>        Signing Identity:     "iPhone Distribution ..."
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign <hash...> <path to DerivedData>/DerivedData/Pop-adpfaxhfjfgnnpbrabyuhgiyxgek/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Pop/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/ReactiveCocoa.framework
> ```
>
> /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pop-adpfaxhfjfgnnpbrabyuhgiyxgek/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Pop/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/ReactiveCocoa.framework:
>   invalid or unsupported format for signature Command /usr/bin/codesign
>   failed with exit code 1

although i verified the ReactiveCocoa.framework is at the specified directory the codeSign is still not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842717/iphone-codesign-object-file-format-invalid-or-unsuitable

Comment: I tried exporting the codesign_allocate from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate but still getting the same error

Comment: What happens if you put ReactiveCocoa only in the DemoFramework?

Comment: Then I wouldn't be able to use it in the DemoApp